# Have figures and tables under sections in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

So currently, the only way to integrate tables and figure in table of contents is to have them setup after the `\tableofcontents` using `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`. My professor asked for a report to have those indented in the table of contents.

Basically, I need to achieve this:
[image: What I want to achieve]
but I only seem to be able to achieve this:
[image: What I currently get]

Here is a copy of my code for this file:

```
\documentclass[11pt, A4]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of contents}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\newpage

\section{First Section}
\begin{figure}[!h]
 \includegraphics[height=3cm]{image}
 \caption{This is an image}
 \label{img}
\end{figure}

\section{Second Section}
\begin{table}[!h]
 \caption{Just a table}
 \label{tabl}
 \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{l|l|c}
   \toprule
     & title &   \\
   \toprule
   a & b     & c \\
   \hline
   d & e     & f \\
   \hline
   g & h     & i
  \end{tabular}
 \end{center}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Here is what the rest of the document looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using `tocbasic` for the format of the figure and table entries (and for the entry of the TOC in the TOC):

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4]{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\ext@figure}{toc}
\renewcommand*{\ext@table}{toc}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\addtotoclist[\jobname]{toc}
\renewcommand*\tableofcontents{\listoftoc[{\contentsname}]{toc}}
\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}% TOC entry in TOC

\newcommand\entrywithprefix[2]{\hfill#1~#2 - }
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  numwidth=6em,
  entrynumberformat=\entrywithprefix{\figurename}
]{tocline}{figure}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  numwidth=6em,
  entrynumberformat=\entrywithprefix{\tablename}
]{tocline}{table}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\section{First Section}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
 \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}
 \caption{This is an image}
 \label{img1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
 \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-b}
 \caption{This is another image}
 \label{img2}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}[htbp]
 \caption{Just a table in first section}
 \label{tabl}
 \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{l|l|c}
   \toprule
     & title &   \\
   \toprule
   a & b     & c \\
   \hline
   d & e     & f \\
   \hline
   g & h     & i
  \end{tabular}
 \end{center}
\end{table}

\section{Second Section}
\begin{table}[htbp]
 \caption{Just a table in second section}
 \label{tabl2}
 \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{l|l|c}
   \toprule
     & title &   \\
   \toprule
   a & b     & c \\
   \hline
   d & e     & f \\
   \hline
   g & h     & i
  \end{tabular}
 \end{center}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
 \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}
 \caption{This is an image in second section}
 \label{img3}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Right now though, tables are labelled as figures and figures as tables... They just need to be switched right after {tocline}.

Comment: Oops. I have corrected that now.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter
\def\ext@figure {toc}
\def\ext@table {toc}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of contents}
\tableofcontents
%\listoftables
%\listoffigures
\newpage

\section{First Section}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
 \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}
 \caption{This is an image}
 \label{img1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
 \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-b}
 \caption{This is another image}
 \label{img2}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}[htbp]
 \caption{Just a table in first section}
 \label{tabl}
 \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{l|l|c}
   \toprule
     & title &   \\
   \toprule
   a & b     & c \\
   \hline
   d & e     & f \\
   \hline
   g & h     & i
  \end{tabular}
 \end{center}
\end{table}

\section{Second Section}
\begin{table}[htbp]
 \caption{Just a table in second section}
 \label{tabl2}
 \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{l|l|c}
   \toprule
     & title &   \\
   \toprule
   a & b     & c \\
   \hline
   d & e     & f \\
   \hline
   g & h     & i
  \end{tabular}
 \end{center}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
 \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}
 \caption{This is an image in second section}
 \label{img3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### update

To obtain this:

[image]

use this in preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\ext@figure{toc}
\def\ext@table {toc}

\let\originalnumberline\numberline

\def\l@figure{\def\numberline##1{\makebox[2cm][l]{Figure\hrulefill##1: }%
                                \global\let\numberline\originalnumberline}%
              \l@subsection}

\def\l@table{\def\numberline##1{\makebox[2cm][l]{Table\hrulefill##1: }%
                                \global\let\numberline\originalnumberline}%
             \l@subsection}
\makeatother
```